# Samples for the azure management sdk for java

Tags: java, azure, sdk

I am looking to use this SDK - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java. However it seems completely devoid of even simple samples. I searched around on the web and the only examples are of using the REST API directly. Is this SDK even supported?

Comment: "Is this SDK even supported?" Not sure what kind of question that is. Did you even look at the [Documentation](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/) page off of azure.com, where there's an entire Java section?

Comment: Hi David - if you had looked at the documentation page of the java section off azure.com you would not be asking me this question. The only documentation is the javadocs which are fairly useless in getting an overview of the SDK and in how it is supposed to be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a blog post on the Azure blog site documenting how you can get started using the SDK with Eclipse and Maven. http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/15/getting-started-with-the-azure-java-management-libraries/

Here's a video demo of the same sort of functionality in action on Channel 9. Apologies for my nervousness that day. :) http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Cloud+Cover/Episode-157-The-Java-SDK-for-Azure-Management-with-Brady-Gaster

Comment: We also have more documentation coming in our Java resources page. I'm working with some of our authors to get more content added. So keep watching the Azure Java area here in the future:http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/java/

Comment: Thanks Brad. Exactly what I was looking for. We are going to be making heavy use of this API over the next few weeks and have some uber questions - where should we ask them?